# Add a selected class to the clicked element and remove it from others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have ul li structure like this

```
     <div id="categoryTree">
  <ul>
    <li id="cat_15"> <a class="hasSubCat"  href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/folder.gif" border="0" alt="Folder" title=" Folder ">North India</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="cat_17"> <a class="hasSubCat"  href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/folder.gif" border="0" alt="Folder" title=" Folder ">All India</a>
          <ul>
            <li id="cat_31"> <a class=""  href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/folder.gif" border="0" alt="Folder" title=" Folder ">First Class</a> </li>
            <li id="cat_32"> <a class=""  href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/folder.gif" border="0" alt="Folder" title=" Folder ">Luxury Level</a> </li>
            <li id="cat_33"> <a class=""  href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/folder.gif" border="0" alt="Folder" title=" Folder ">Oulent Level</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="cat_16"> <a class="hasSubCat"  href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/folder.gif" border="0" alt="Folder" title=" Folder ">South India</a> </li>
    <li id="cat_37"> <a class=""  href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/folder.gif" border="0" alt="Folder" title=" Folder ">All India</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i wan to add a selected class to the clicked and remove it from others

i am using following code to do this

```
$('#categoryTree li').on('click',function(){
        $('#categoryTree li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
```

but every time class is added to the top li.please help .....
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of event propagation, where the click event in a child get propagated to the parent element. You can prevent it by calling [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation);

```
$('#categoryTree li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#categoryTree .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).find('a').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: still adding the class only to top li only

Comment: sir your answer worked for the sitaution . How would i handle it if every ul inside li is loading with ajax call on every click on li.

Comment: @yogesh84 which example worked for you first or second.... for ajax loaded content you need to use event delegation... once you say which one worked then we can change it to work with dynamic content

Comment: thanks a lot this worked well -jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/71smdasa/4

Answer (score 1):

I dont see an id of #categoryTree so we are missing some information here but it seems you want to remove the class from the selected siblings. You can do that like this...

```
$('#categoryTree li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, using `e.stopPropagation()` which prevents the bubbling of event to parent `li`.

```
$('#categoryTree li').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest("div").find("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```